# How to solve OS error showing incorrect path

Tags: python

I want code which can delete all files present in a folder, read the folder by his path from text file.I have tried below code but showing error:

> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'F:\New folder\n'

My original path is:F:\New folder

```py
import os
import shutil
import time


def get_drive_usage(path):
    usage = shutil.disk_usage(path)
    BytesPerGB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
    percent_utilization = ("Used_percent: %.2f" % (float(usage.used/usage.total)*100))
    print(percent_utilization)
    print("Total: %.2fGB" % (float(usage.total)/BytesPerGB)),
    print("Used:  %.2fGB" % (float(usage.used)/BytesPerGB)),
    print("free:  %.2fGB" % (float(usage.free)/BytesPerGB))
    if percent_utilization > '20':
        file = open('folder_name','r')
        content = file.read()
        print(content)
        print(os.listdir(content))
        for f in os.listdir(content):
            os.remove(os.path.join(content,f))
            print("file removed")


get_drive_usage("F:\\")
```

Expected result: it has to delete the file from given path but it showing incorrect path.

Comment: According to the error message, there is an extraneous `\n` at the end of the file name. Remove it with `content = file.read().strip()`.

Comment: can you please share the path that is present in the text file

Comment: Why you want to read a file with the name ''folder_name" ?  `file = open('folder_name','r')
        content = file.read()`

Comment: F:\New folder    : this path is present in text file

Comment: thank you so much to Thierry Lathuille, it works